# PHP Design Patterns: Are private constructors bad for classes that you will let others to extend?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, open-source

I have an abstract class called `ContentAbstract` which looks something like this

```
abstract class ContentAbstract
{
  protected static $type;
  protected $id;
  protected $title;
  protected $description;

  protected $page;
  protected $section;
  ...

  function __construct($id = NULL, Page $page = NULL, Section $section = NULL)
  {
    if($id != NULL)
    {
      $data = get_data_from_content_table_by_id($id);

      if($data['type'] == static::$type)
      {
        initialize_fields_with_data($data);

        $this->page = fetch_page_object_from_registry($data['page_id']);
        $this->section = fetch_section_object_from_registry($data['section_id']);
      }
      else
        throw new IncompatibleContentTypeException('Foo');
    }
    else if($page != NULL && $section != NULL)
    {
      $this->page = $page;
      $this->section = $section;
    }
    else
      throw new OphanContentException('Foo');
  }
}
```

Then the `Page` Class is also a subclass of `ContentAbstract`

```
class Page extends ContentAbstract
{
  protected static $type = 'Page';

  private $template_file;
  private $short_name;

  static function newFromName($name)
  {
    $data = get_content_id_from_page_table_using_the_short_name($name);
    $page = new Page($data['id']);
    $page->template_file = $data['template_file'];
    ...
  }

  static function newFromID($id)
  {
    $data = get_content_id_from_page_table_using_the_ID($id);
    $page = new Page($data['id']);
    $page->template_file = $data['template_file'];
    ...
  }
}
```

Now my problem lies in the fact that the `Page` constructor is public and users can do this:

```
$page = new Page($valid_page_id);
```

and end up calling `ContentAbstract::__construct()` but not being able to initialize the data for the page itself (`template_file`, and `short_name`) since it was called outside of `Page::newFromName()` and `Page::newFromID()`. So I end up with a *half-cooked* content data. One solution would be to override the parent constructor with something similar to `Page::newFromID()` making sure that we would be able to set all fields when the `Page` is instantiated (of course by still calling the parent constructor within `Page::__construct()`).

Now the problem lies in the `Page::newFromName()` method since such an approach will require me to make 2 queries, one is to get the content id of the page using the `short_name` column, and then when the constructor of the page is called within `Page::newFromName()`, it will then create a new query to get the data associated with the page. That's not desirable isn't it?

So the only solution I see is to make `Page::__construct()` private and force end users to use the static methods to instantiate the object.

My question is, this is something I'd like to release as an open source project and it allows users to add more types of contents by simply subclassing the `ContentAbstract` class. Is requiring a private constructor detrimental to the said objective (accounting for human error and the laziness to read through documentation)? Or should such matters  be the least of my concerns? Or are the structures of the actual classes themselves lend to this problem?

Comment: Ahhhh... But how do I know if the constructor is called from within the class itself?

Comment: I realized I had misread what you wanted to do and so my suggestions were misguided -- sorry for that wandering off topic. I deleted my comments on the matter so as not to confuse anyone!

Answer (score 0):

"Now my problem lies in the fact that the Page constructor is public and users can do this:

$page = new Page($valid_page_id);"

According to the code you posted in the OP this shouldn't be the case. Your page extends ContentAbstract where the construct resides, but you aren't actually calling construct from the Page class. You would have to force a call to the parent from the child:

```
class Page extends Content // I wouldn't name this abstract as it may change in the future
{
    public function __construct($args)
    {
        // Here I forced a call to parent
        // If I comment this out, the parent construct will never be accessed
        parent::__construct($args); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the problem is that I never did override the parent constructor so the `Page` constructor is also public. Thus, as long as I pass a valid ID in `new Page($id)`, the script won't complain. However, since all the initialization of the Page's properties are done in the static methods, only the inherited properties will be set that way.

Comment: @RolandoCruz: Ahhh of course. When I implement a construct like you have I always override it.

Comment: @RolandoCruz: Just had an idea, why don't you move the contents of ContentAbstract::__construct() to a `protected init()` method. This way the code can't be directly accessed upon instantiation, yet your static methods can still init the member variables?

Comment: @RolandoCruz: What did you end up doing to resolve your issue?